# Loading multiple doughnut chart from chart.JS in a single component of angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, chart.js, pie-chart

I have a component in which i have to show 2 doughnut chart. and then i have another component which will load the chart after getting the dataset from previous component.
after passing different data and different id none of the charts are getting loaded.

Here is my code :-
parent component HTML:-

```
<div class="card chart radial-chart match-time col-sm-3">
        <label class="card-title">Match Time</label>
        <app-chart-component [data]='matchingChartData' [id]=1></app-chart-component>
    </div>
    <div class="card chart radial-chart passage-time col-sm-3">
        <label class="card-title">Passage Time</label>
        <app-chart-component [data]='PassagerChartData' [id]=2></app-chart-component>
    </div>
```

parent component ts : -

```
matchingChartData = {
labels : ['Minimum','Maximum', 'Average'],
datasets: [
  { 
    data: [2.4,2.8, 5],
    backgroundColor: ['blue','red','green' ]
  },
]
```

};

```
 PassageChartData = {
labels : ['Minimum','Maximum', 'Average'],
datasets: [
  { 
    data: [2.4,2.8, 2.6],
    backgroundColor: ['green','red','yellow' ]
  },
]
```

}

chart component HTML:-

```
<canvas id={{uniqueId}}></canvas>
```

Chart component ts :-

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart-component',
    templateUrl: './chart-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./chart-component.component.css']
  })
  export class ChartComponentComponent implements OnInit {
    chart: any;
    uniqueId: any;
    @Input() data: any;
    @Input() id:number;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.uniqueId = 'canvas'+this.id;;
      this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
          labels: this.data.labels,
          datasets: this.data.datasets
        },
        options: {
          cutoutPercentage: 85,
          rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
          circumference: 1 * Math.PI,
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
          tooltips:{
            enabled:true,
            titleFontSize: 26,
            bodyFontSize: 26
          }
              }
      });
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

chart component HTML:-

```
<canvas id="{{uniqueId}}"></canvas>
```

or

```
<canvas [id]="uniqueId"></canvas>
```

Comment: Check that the id is set for canvas by inspect element

Comment: yes, id is getting set for canvas element.and there is no error in console.

Answer (score 0):

Chart component ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input,ViewChild,AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart-component',
    templateUrl: './chart-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./chart-component.component.css']
  })
  export class ChartComponentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    chart: any;
    uniqueId: any;
    @Input() data: any;
    @Input() id:number;
    @ViewChild('canvas', { static: false }) canvas: ElementRef;
    public context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.context = (<HTMLCanvasElement>this.canvas.nativeElement).getContext('2d');
      this.uniqueId = 'canvas'+this.id;
      this.chart = new Chart(this.context, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
          labels: this.data.labels,
          datasets: this.data.datasets
        },
        options: {
          cutoutPercentage: 85,
          rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
          circumference: 1 * Math.PI,
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
          tooltips:{
            enabled:true,
            titleFontSize: 26,
            bodyFontSize: 26
          }
              }
      });
    }

  }
```

chart component HTML:

```
<canvas #canvas [id]="uniqueId"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is giving error in chart.js inbuilt file, Could you please create any fiddle or demo.